# PHP simple packing items in boxes leads to unused space but there is capacity left

Tags: php, packing

I have a really simplistic approach to the packing of items as a PHP Script and I need to know if it's possible to minimize the leftover space inside the boxes where the items will be placed.

My code so far:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['capacity'] = 330;

function PackIt($capacity, $items)
{
    usort($items, function ($a, $b) {
        $areaA = $a['width'] * $a['height'];
        $areaB = $b['width'] * $b['height'];
        return $areaB - $areaA;
    });

    $boxes = [];
    $currentBox = ['width' => 0, 'height' => 0, 'items' => []];

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemWidth = $item['width'];
        $itemHeight = $item['height'];

        // Check if the item fits in the current box
        if ($itemWidth <= $capacity - $currentBox['width']) {
            $currentBox['items'][] = $item;
            $currentBox['width'] += $itemWidth;
            $currentBox['height'] = max($currentBox['height'], $itemHeight);
        } else {
            // If the item doesn't fit, create a new box and add the item
            $boxes[] = $currentBox;
            $currentBox = ['width' => $itemWidth, 'height' => $itemHeight, 'items' => [$item]];
        }
    }

    $boxes[] = $currentBox;

    return $boxes;
}

function generateHTML($boxes)
{
    $capacity = $GLOBALS['capacity'];
    $htmlFragments = [];

    foreach ($boxes as $boxIndex => $box) {
        $htmlFragments[] = '<h3>Box ' . ($boxIndex + 1) . ' ('.$capacity.'x'.$capacity.')</h3>';
        $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="box" style="border:1px solid #333; box-sizing:border-box; width:' . $capacity . 'px; height:' . $capacity . 'px;">';
        $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="items">';

        foreach ($box['items'] as $item) {
            $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="item" style="float:left;">';
            $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:' . $item['width'] . 'px; height:' . $item['height'] . 'px;">' . $item['name'] . '<span class="item-dimensions"> (' . $item['width'] . 'x' . $item['height'] . ')</span></div>';
            $htmlFragments[] = '</div>';
        }

        $htmlFragments[] = '</div>';

        // Calculate remaining capacity for the box
        $boxArea = 330 * 330;
        $occupiedArea = 0;

        foreach ($box['items'] as $item) {
            $itemWidth = $item['width'];
            $itemHeight = $item['height'];
            $occupiedArea += $itemWidth * $itemHeight;
        }

        $htmlFragments[] = '</div>';
        $remainingCapacity = $boxArea - $occupiedArea;
        $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="remaining-capacity" style="clear:both;">The remaining capacity is: ' . $remainingCapacity . '</div>';
    }


    return implode('', $htmlFragments);
}

$capacity = $GLOBALS['capacity'];
$items = [
    ['name' => 'Item A', 'width' => 100, 'height' => 295],
    ['name' => 'Item B', 'width' => 145, 'height' => 315],
    ['name' => 'Item C', 'width' => 80, 'height' => 300],
    ['name' => 'Item D', 'width' => 60, 'height' => 160],
    ['name' => 'Item E', 'width' => 20, 'height' => 60],
    ['name' => 'Item F', 'width' => 60, 'height' => 180],
    ['name' => 'Item G', 'width' => 30, 'height' => 50],
    ['name' => 'Item H', 'width' => 70, 'height' => 300],
    // ... more items
];

$boxes = PackIt($capacity, $items);

// Generate HTML
$htmlOutput = generateHTML($boxes);

echo $htmlOutput;

?>
```

Which leads to the Output:
Box 1 (330x330)
Item B (145x315)
Item A (100x295)
Item C (80x300)
The remaining capacity is: 9725

Box 2 (330x330)
Item H (70x300)
Item F (60x180)
Item D (60x160)
Item E (20x60)
Item G (30x50)
The remaining capacity is: 63600

```html
Output:
<h3>Box 1 (330x330)</h3><div class="box" style="border:1px solid #333; box-sizing:border-box; width:330px; height:330px;"><div class="items"><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:145px; height:315px;">Item B<span class="item-dimensions"> (145x315)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:100px; height:295px;">Item A<span class="item-dimensions"> (100x295)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:80px; height:300px;">Item C<span class="item-dimensions"> (80x300)</span></div></div></div></div><div class="remaining-capacity" style="clear:both;">The remaining capacity is: 9725</div><h3>Box 2 (330x330)</h3><div class="box" style="border:1px solid #333; box-sizing:border-box; width:330px; height:330px;"><div class="items"><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:70px; height:300px;">Item H<span class="item-dimensions"> (70x300)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:60px; height:180px;">Item F<span class="item-dimensions"> (60x180)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:60px; height:160px;">Item D<span class="item-dimensions"> (60x160)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:30px; height:50px;">Item G<span class="item-dimensions"> (30x50)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:20px; height:60px;">Item E<span class="item-dimensions"> (20x60)</span></div></div></div></div><div class="remaining-capacity" style="clear:both;">The remaining capacity is: 64800</div>
```

**Why won't Item E and G not fit into box 1 as well?**

Comment: A visual representation really could help here, can your code generate one? Does your code try to rotate the elements to fit in the box? Maybe you should add a simple description of how your code tries to fit items in a box

Comment: Hello @Kaddath I've added the generated HTML Code to visualize the Output accordingly. At this point a rotation is not implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the visual representation, it shows without doubt that the E and G elements have no room to fit in without being rotated first, so I guess this is your answer, you need to implement rotation for them to fit

Comment: Yep I think so too and that's the hard part to achieve currently.

Comment: Yes the way you started your code does not really leave room for advanced item fitting. If this can help, you can view the capacity in term of a list of rectangles of free space instead of a subtraction of total capacity and fitted items. Maybe it's a bad idea I don't know, but it would allow easier comparison to see if it fits (and a harder code for the free space)

Comment: Actually I think optimal items arrangement is not a trivial problem (and gets worse in 3D), there should be studies and algorithms already made for that, never had to do it myself though, and it's a good exercise if you wanted to do this for practice

Comment: It is NP-Hard very very many approaches. I thought I might get a simple approach to work. Still struggling with the rotation. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_packing

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution in OOPs way.
I have created a Box class and a Package class.

**Box class:**

Initialize with box capacity and checked if item can fit into box or not and if it fit into box I decrease box capacity.

**Package class:**

It initializes with items and capacity, it has pack method which check no of items and add new box if required and check available space in boxes.

```
<?php
class Box
{
    protected $area;
    protected $capacity;
    protected $items;
    private int $availableWidth;

    public function __construct($capacity)
    {
        $this->capacity = $capacity;
        $this->area = $capacity * $capacity;
        $this->availableWidth = $capacity;
    }

    private function addItem($item)
    {
        $unUsedSpace = 0;

        $remain = $this->capacity - $item['height'];
        $item['space_left'] = [
            'height' => $remain,
            'width' => $this->availableWidth,
            'area' => $this->availableWidth * $remain
        ];
        $unUsedSpace = $this->availableWidth * $remain;
        $this->availableWidth -= $item['width'];
        $this->items[] = $item;
        $this->area = $this->area - $unUsedSpace;
    }

    private function addItemVertically($item)
    {
        $unUsedSpace = 0;

        $remain = $this->capacity - $item['height'];
        $item['space_left'] = [
            'height' => $remain,
            'width' => $this->availableWidth,
            'area' => $this->availableWidth * $remain
        ];
        $unUsedSpace = $this->availableWidth * $remain;
        $this->availableWidth -= $item['height'];

        $newItem = [
            'name' => $item['name'],
            'width' => $item['height'],
            'height' => $item['width'],
            'space_left' => $item['space_left']
        ];

        $this->items[] = $newItem;
        $this->area = $this->area - $unUsedSpace;
    }

    public function canItemFitInBox($item)
    {
        if (!empty($this->items)) {
            if ($this->availableWidth >= $item['width'] && $this->capacity >= $item['height']) {
                $this->addItem($item);
                return true;
            } elseif ($this->availableWidth >= $item['height'] && $this->capacity >= $item['width']) {
                $this->addItemVertically($item);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $this->addItem($item);
        return true;
    }

    public function canItemFitInLeftSpace($item)
    {
        foreach ($this->items as $space) {
            //compare left space height with item width
            $itemArea = $item['width'] * $item['height'];
            $spaceArea = $space['space_left']['area'];
            if (
                $space['space_left']['height'] >= $item['width']
                && $space['space_left']['width'] >= $item['height']
                && $spaceArea >= $itemArea
            ) {
                $space['space_left']['height'] -= $item['width'];
                $space['space_left']['width'] -= $item['height'];
                $space['space_left']['area'] -= $itemArea;
                $this->addItemVertically($item);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
}

class Package
{
    public array $boxes = [];
    public function __construct(public array $items, public int $capacity)
    {
        /* usort($this->items, function ($a, $b) {
            return $b['height'] - $a['height'];
        }); */
        usort($this->items, function ($a, $b) {
            $areaA = $a['width'] * $a['height'];
            $areaB = $b['width'] * $b['height'];
            return $areaB - $areaA;
        });
    }

    public function addNewBox()
    {
        $this->boxes[] = new Box($this->capacity);
    }

    public function checkSpaceInAvailableBoxes($item, $key)
    {
        foreach ($this->boxes as $box) {
            if ($box->canItemFitInBox($item)) {
                unset($this->items[$key]);
            } elseif ($box->canItemFitInLeftSpace($item)) {
                unset($this->items[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function pack()
    {
        while (!empty($this->items)) {
            $this->addNewBox($this->capacity);
            foreach ($this->items as $key => $item) {
                $this->checkSpaceInAvailableBoxes($item, $key);
            }
        }

        return $this->boxes;
    }
}

function generateHTML($boxes, $capacity)
{
    $htmlFragments = [];

    foreach ($boxes as $boxIndex => $box) {
        $htmlFragments[] = '<h3>Box ' . ($boxIndex + 1) . '<span>(' . $capacity . 'x' . $capacity . ')</span></h3>';
        $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="box" style="border:1px solid #333; box-sizing:border-box; width:' . $capacity . 'px; height:' . $capacity . 'px;">';
        $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="items">';

        $boxItems = $box->getItems();
        foreach ($boxItems as $item) {
            $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="item" style="float:left;">';
            $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="item-name" style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;text-orientation: mixed; border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:' . $item['width'] . 'px; height:' . $item['height'] . 'px;">' . $item['name'] . '<span class="item-dimensions"> (' . $item['width'] . 'x' . $item['height'] . ')</span></div>';
            $htmlFragments[] = '</div>';
        }

        $htmlFragments[] = '</div>';

        // Calculate remaining capacity for the box
        $boxArea = 330 * 330;
        $occupiedArea = 0;

        foreach ($boxItems as $item) {
            $itemWidth = $item['width'];
            $itemHeight = $item['height'];
            $occupiedArea += $itemWidth * $itemHeight;
        }

        $htmlFragments[] = '</div>';
        $remainingCapacity = $boxArea - $occupiedArea;
        $htmlFragments[] = '<div class="remaining-capacity" style="clear:both;">The remaining capacity is: ' . $remainingCapacity . '</div>';
    }


    return implode('', $htmlFragments);
}

$capacity = 330;
$items = [
    ['name' => 'Item A', 'width' => 100, 'height' => 295],
    ['name' => 'Item B', 'width' => 145, 'height' => 315],
    ['name' => 'Item C', 'width' => 80, 'height' => 300],
    ['name' => 'Item D', 'width' => 60, 'height' => 160],
    ['name' => 'Item E', 'width' => 20, 'height' => 60],
    ['name' => 'Item F', 'width' => 60, 'height' => 180],
    ['name' => 'Item G', 'width' => 30, 'height' => 50],
    ['name' => 'Item H', 'width' => 70, 'height' => 300],
    // ... more items
];

$package = new Package($items, $capacity);
$box = $package->pack();

echo generateHTML($box, $capacity);
```

**Output**

```html
<h3>Box 1 (330x330)</h3><div class="box" style="border:1px solid #333; box-sizing:border-box; width:330px; height:330px;"><div class="items"><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:145px; height:315px;">Item B<span class="item-dimensions"> (145x315)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:80px; height:300px;">Item C<span class="item-dimensions"> (80x300)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:70px; height:300px;">Item H<span class="item-dimensions"> (70x300)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:20px; height:60px;">Item E<span class="item-dimensions"> (20x60)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:30px; height:50px;">Item G<span class="item-dimensions"> (30x50)</span></div></div></div></div><div class="remaining-capacity" style="clear:both;">The remaining capacity is: 15525</div><h3>Box 2 (330x330)</h3><div class="box" style="border:1px solid #333; box-sizing:border-box; width:330px; height:330px;"><div class="items"><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:100px; height:295px;">Item A<span class="item-dimensions"> (100x295)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:90px; height:200px;">Item J<span class="item-dimensions"> (90x200)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:60px; height:180px;">Item F<span class="item-dimensions"> (60x180)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:60px; height:160px;">Item D<span class="item-dimensions"> (60x160)</span></div></div><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:40px; height:90px;">Item I<span class="item-dimensions"> (40x90)</span></div></div></div></div><div class="remaining-capacity" style="clear:both;">The remaining capacity is: 37400</div><h3>Box 3 (330x330)</h3><div class="box" style="border:1px solid #333; box-sizing:border-box; width:330px; height:330px;"><div class="items"><div class="item" style="float:left;"><div class="item-name" style="border:1px solid #CCC; box-sizing:border-box; width:160px; height:110px;">Item K<span class="item-dimensions"> (160x110)</span></div></div></div></div><div class="remaining-capacity" style="clear:both;">The remaining capacity is: 91300</div>
```

Comment: IMO the total capacity is not enough to check if an item can fit. We can see from the visual example that D cannot fit in the first box when B, A and C are there. There is another check based on the dimension of the item to add somewhere..

Comment: @Kaddath yes I think so too. It was just my simplified approach to see if capacity is left or negative. When having the real dimension to fit an item in it might be taller than the dimension of the box.

Comment: @Pragnesh Chauhan, thanks for providing code for the given problem. I wanted to make it run for investigation and traceability but wasn't able to run it. All I get is Error 500.

Comment: @huppen please make sure you're using PHP 8.1 or latest version.

Comment: You're right it needs PHP 8.1 and works so far. Like Kaddath mentioned the capacity is not enough and was just my simplified method to prevent it to be negative when do the coding. When our Boxdimension is 330 to 330 the "Item D" won't fit into the remaining space.

Comment: @huppen, Yes I understood and working on it.

Comment: This looks really promising. I need more testing although to prove it for my scenario. Keep you updated.

Comment: @huppen I have fixed issue with left over space and updated my version.

Comment: @Pragnesh Chauhan great work, in the version before I had an issue where Items where double placed in certain cases with smaller dimensions. Now the new version seems to fix this as well. Thanks a lot for participating here :-)

Comment: @Pragnesh Chauhan I had the time to test with more reliable data which leads to unexpected behaviour. Sometimes a box is packed but the space left is for example -109972. Do you have a clue why it won't pack into another box?

Comment: @huppen, I will check it later.